# How to create a scope variable easily in R

Tags: r, scope, global-variables

I would like to create an variable *x* that receives *3*. It is created another scope, where *x* receives *1*. But, as the scope ends, *x* value will return to 3. How can I do it?

What I mean is shown in the code below. I would like to do something like this:

```
x <- 3
{x = 1
print (x)}  //{} Is the way I thought to make x=1 be in another scope 
print (x)
```

That has the output as this:

```
[1] 1
[1] 1
```

But I would like the output to be:

```
[1] 1
[1] 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to work in a different environment. See http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html

One easy way to do this is to use a function.

```
x <- 3
funky <- function() {
  x = 1
  print (x)
  }
funky()  
# [1] 1
print (x)
# [1] 3
```

Alternatively, you can specify an environment.

```
e <- new.env()
x <- 3
e$x <- 1
e$x
# [1] 1
x
# [1] 3
```

@Dason brought up a good point that the function `local` simplifies handling the alternate environment.

```
x <- 3
local({
  x <- 1
  print(x)
})
# [1] 1
print(x)
# [1] 3
```

from `help(local)`

> local evaluates an expression in a local environment. It is equivalent
>   to evalq except that its default argument creates a new, empty
>   environment. This is useful to create anonymous recursive functions
>   and as a kind of limited namespace feature since variables defined in
>   the environment are not visible from the outside.

Comment: The 'local' function is something you might want to mention too

Comment: `local` is new to me, but seems to be exactly what the OP needs. I've updated the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Functions have local variables and will look there first before checking for global variables. So you could do something like this

```
print_x = function(){
  x = 3
  print(x)
}

x = 1

> print(x)
[1] 1
> print_x()
[1] 3
```